# mongodb: How to do group and aggregation on array fields

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb, a collection named 'blog' has a 'tags' field, just like this

```
blog1.tags=['javascript', 'node.js', 'express'] 
blog2.tags=['javascript', 'jquery']
blog3.tags=['javascript', 'node.js']
```

now I need a hot tag list, which like this

```
[['javascript', 3], ['node.js', 2], ['express', 1], ['jquery', 1]]
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Please do basic search by using a simple google search and you will find this: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/

Comment: You can use aggregation pipeline like group({"_id":"tags","count":{"$sum":1}})

Answer (score 2):

In Mongodb 2.2 you will be able to use the aggregation framework and the $unwind and $group commands.  Check out their [demo here](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/mongodbs-new-aggregation-framework) and the [demo source code](https://gist.github.com/1401585).